# Pushing input value to array in local storage goes wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

For a project I'm working on I want to store a value from an inputfield in a array thats being stored in localstorage. By looking up older questions on here I've managed to get a long way already, but still something isn't going right. When I use console.log to check if my array is being filled after I've entered something, it shows a bunch of nested arrays in my console of which I don't know how to fix/work with.

My js:

```
names = [];
names.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname')));
localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));

function saveData(data) {

  names = [];
  var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
  names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname'));
  names.push(data);
  alert(names);
  localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));
}

console.log(names);
```

In my HTML I have a input with id=locationName, and a button with onclick=saveData().

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
// Read value from storage, or empty array.
// You were doing something different here - you were putting array
// from localStorage into your "names" array, so for every page refresh
// you would make this structure deeper by 1.
var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname') || "[]");

function saveData(data) {
  var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
  names.push(data);
  localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));
}
```

[Working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaBdx/4/) (use developer tools to see local storage contents).

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! Your explanation made me realize what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put in your array `names` the one you get from local storage.

Change

```
names = [];
names.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname')));
localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));
```

to

```
var names = []; // always declare your variables
if (localStorage.getItem('locname')) {
    names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname'));
}
```