# Saving Usernames in Local Storage. Only by using one key.

Tags: javascript, list, local-storage

I want to save and get out the Usernames from the Local Storage. I can only save and get out one Username with one key. Is it possible to save the Usernames in an array so that I can list them later ? I think it actually overwrites itself..

```
//Saving the username from input field to the Local Storage
top.username=document.getElementById("name").value;
localStorage.setItem('user', top.username);

//Getting out the username from the Local Storage
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML =localStorage.getItem('user');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('arrayOfUserNames', JSON.stringify(['foo']))

var arrayOfUserNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrayOfUserNames'))

arrayOfUserNames.push('bar')

localStorage.setItem('arrayOfUserNames', JSON.stringify(arrayOfUserNames))

arrayOfUserNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrayOfUserNames'))

console.log(arrayOfUserNames) // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn`t fixed the problem.. I still get the same output

Comment: Okay now I fixed it through this here ! :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045623/pushing-input-value-to-array-in-local-storage-goes-wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 let loginForm = this.loginForm.value;
 localStorage.setItem('userName', JSON.stringify([loginForm.userName]));
 localStorage.setItem('password', JSON.stringify([loginForm.password]));
```